# Access google maps markers on external website with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebug, google-maps-markers

I am looking into how websites using google maps are put together and I want to access map elements on these website interactively using the firebug console.

For example, with this link...
http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=eh13&hl=en&z=12&vpsrc=0

You can type into the console:

```
gApplication.getMap().getCenter();
```

And the latitude & longitude will be printed.

However for this link...
http://www.primelocation.com/uk-property-for-sale/search/?p=eh13&ls=0
I cant figure out how to refer to the map in javascript and how I can find the coordinates of each of the map markers.

Any help on how to analyse websites like this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have an 'object', Maps, they've created to handle their map.  They store it in the variable window.map.  You can get the center of the map by typing this in the console:

```
window.map.mapOptions.center
```

Here is where they define the object:

http://www.primelocation.com/content/scripts/map/tdpgmap.js

Comment: Thanks @akellehe that worked. As far as I can see, although the map itself is an object you can get at, the markers are just created within methods and I dont think there is a way of referencing them.

Answer (score 0):

Try **google.maps** in the console log you will have access to some properties ... i think

Comment: Thanks @Tarek. That worked. I was unable to get at the markers though. I had though that the markers would be properties of the map object but looking at the google API I dont believe this is the case. You create markers using the Markers() method of the google.maps but as far as I can see there is no connection to the map object.

Answer (score 0):

You can gain access to the map on the page you linked in Chrome by accessing `this.map` in the debugging console (press Ctrl+Shift+I and click Console).

I would add that it is rather difficult to determine what variable (if any) holds the Google map object for a given page without analyzing all stored JavaScript variables to see whether they are of the type `google.maps.Map`.